# Referencing columns from nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g, and I get an error when using nested SQL queries.

When I try to run the following query, I get

> "U.RSRC_ID": invalid identifier*

Here is the SQL query

```
SELECT u.first_name,
u.RSRC_ID,
(SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (dn, ',') ,2) FROM
   (
      SELECT USER_NAME as dn, RSRC_ID as rsccid,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY user_name ) rn,
      COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
      FROM ADDRLOOKUP
      WHERE RSRC_ID  IN (u.RSRC_ID) AND primary_addr=4
   )
   WHERE rn        = cnt
   START WITH rn = 1
   CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1 
) AS multipleDn

FROM USERINFO u
WHERE u.RSRC_ID      IN (123,124) ;
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question.

Comment: is not this pl/SQL ? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: No. PL/SQL is for stored procedures. This is just plain SQL.

Comment: Thanks you for your answering. Do you have any solution for above problem?

Comment: Edgars answered the direct question. It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. Maybe you should take a step back and tell us what the actual problem is you are trying to solve. For that, **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can reference outer layer just 1 level deep. In this case you are referencing columns 2 levels deeper. It is in line 9 :

```
WHERE RSRC_ID  IN (u.RSRC_ID)
```

Edit: You could rewrite inner select and bring filter one level up, that would not be good for performance, but result should be ok:

```
SELECT u.first_name,
u.RSRC_ID,
(SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (dn, ',') ,2) FROM
   (
      SELECT USER_NAME as dn, RSRC_ID as rsccid,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by RSRC_ID ORDER BY user_name) rn,
      COUNT (*) OVER (partition by RSRC_ID) cnt
      FROM ADDRLOOKUP
      WHERE primary_addr=4
   )
   WHERE rn        = cnt
     and rsccid = u.RSRC_ID
   START WITH rn = 1
   CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1 
) AS multipleDn
FROM USERINFO u
WHERE u.RSRC_ID IN (123,124) ;
```

Comment: is there any way to reference 2 deep levels ?